# Can in-memory tables be added to a database diagram

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016, diagram

I have a SQL Server 2016 database with in-memory tables. I'd like to use the database diagram feature to create a graphic to match.

Running SSMS 18.3.1. When I start a new diagram, the in-memory tables are not shown in the drop down. Is there another way to get them on the diagram?

Note: In the official documentation these are called memory-optimized tables.  See [Introduction to Memory-Optimized Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/introduction-to-memory-optimized-tables)

Comment: To my way of thinking, "in-memory tables" really exist for one purpose:  to enable stored procedures to return multiple rows.  They're a very special-purpose construction.  I really can't envision them being part of "a diagram."  And I can't visualize how *your* database is using them ...

Comment: I'm referring to the memory-optimized tables, often called in-memory tables.  Were using them as described in the official docs.  I added a link to the top post

Comment: You could open `Output windows` in SSMS. `Ctrl+Alt+O`. Then accessing diagram feature you should be able to intercept query sent to retrieve metadata. I bet it is built in a way that exclude InMemory Tables.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Interesting idea.  However I see no diagram related queries *at all* in the output window.

Answer (score 3):

OLTP is not supported for database diagram. You do not have access to **in-memory tables**  in the diagram because the diagram does not recognize the essence of a in-memory tables as a table, in fact SQL Server generates a DLL for each created Memory-Optimized Table Type that includes the functions required 
for accessing the indexes and retrieving data from the related Memory-Optimized Table Variable

Comment: Yes, i know how SQL Server builds DLLs for these,  just looking for a definitive source stating that mem-opt tables are not available in diagrams.  Do you have a source like that?

Answer (score 3):

You can't add **OLTP** object in Database Diagram, not in even in SQL Server 2019.

I thought there should be a way to modify `[definition]` column in `[dbo].[sysdiagrams]` but it is HexString of unknown file type. (I tried many formats but its obviously an internal Microsoft type)

Unfortunately, there is no reference to mention that is a not-supported feature. (I send a comment to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/unsupported-sql-server-features-for-in-memory-oltp?view=sql-server-ver15#feedback) )

Comment: I hope your comment is accepted (OTOH you could branch the source, add the comment and send in a PR.  It might get more attention.  Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the SQL Profiler tool you'll see there is a column name IsMemoryOptimized in the table data result set that is returned for the memory-optimized table. I think since the Database Diagrams functionality is older (since mssql 2000) and not updated regularly it does not support viewing the newer memory-optimized tables.

more info here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/71aa7b6e-c281-4417-8149-2eb6f3830110/sql-server-2016-memory-optimized-tables-not-visible-in-database-diagrams?forum=sqlinmemory

Comment: Yes it appears not to work, that is true.  just looking for an official statement to that effect.